# windows.opener not working in external pages

Tags: javascript

Eu desenvolvi um sistema que funciona em meu servidor, mas não nos de terceiros. Quando clico para deslogar, executo a função onunload com o windows.opener, para fechar a janela automaticamente e, mudar o status do login nas janelas pais.
Funciona no meu server, mas não no dos outros.

Veja meu código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onunload = refreshParent;
    function refreshParent() {
        window.opener.VerificarLogin("<?php echo $_SESSION["usuario"]["email"]; ?>","<?php echo $_SESSION["usuario"]["codigo"]; ?>"); 
    }
    window.close();
</script>
```

obs: Estou tentando criar a mesma coisa que o sistema disqus (sistema de comentários) faz. Quando você dá um logout, eles mudam o status do login não para uma janela, mas em todas automaticamente.

Comment: Quando dizes que não funciona noutros servidores, implementaste código nos outros servidores ou somente JavaScript?

Comment: Somente javascript. Eu coloquei no server e estou tentando acessar via localhost, o que funciona, porém, quando você tenta executar essas funções que eu citei em uma página externa, não gera efeito nenhum. obs: A janela até fecha, mas o windows.opener não envia nenhum dado.

Comment: O que tem essa função `VerificarLogin`? se tiver uma chamada ajax duvido que o browser tenha tempo de enviar antes de fechar. Pode ser um problema intermitente...

Comment: Apenas códigos javascript que alteram determinado conteúdo de uma div como: document.getElementById .

Comment: Como assim? em cima referiste _"o windows.opener não envia nenhum dado"_, é essa parte que acho que vai falhar porque o browser está a fechar e abrir um ajax novo acho que pode falhar.

Comment: Depois que executa o onunload, a janela fecha corretamente, mas depois, que é preciso enviar o javascript para a janela pai com aqueles dados, não funciona. obs: Dentro do server tudo isso funciona, é quando eu tento usar isso externamente nos sites dos outros que dá problema. É como se a janela que foi fechada não soubesse da onde veio. obs: O que eu quero fazer também tem no sistema de comentários do facebook. você clica em publicar, ele abre uma janela, e quando se loga corretamente a janela se fecha e muda o status de login, Tudo em páginas externas.

Comment: _"enviar o javascript para a janela pai"_ - estás a usar iFrames?

Comment: Não, estou usando XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: A que é que te referes quando dizes _"janela pai"_?

Comment: A página que quando clicada, abre uma outra janela com o window.opener, cuja os resultados deveriam afetar a página que a criou.

Comment: Ok, está mais claro obrigado. Então e o código que envia ajax para o servidor está na página pai certo? como estás a inserir o script na página "filha"? é esse script que tens em cima certo?

Comment: Sim, é isso mesmo.

Comment: Tava pesquisando aqui... Parece que por razões de segurança, o window.opener não funciona quando utilizado em um domínio diferente

Comment: Faz sentido. Se for uma fonte segura podes mesmo colocar isso como resposta.

Comment: Parece sim, olha o link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18625733/how-do-i-get-around-window-opener-cross-domain-security/18712160#18712160   Vou testar para ver se funciona. Obrigado pela ajuda ai!.